# Run external command from within Perl

Tags: windows, perl

I am using Doxygen to generate HTML documentation and then run a Perl script to get function names.

To run Doxygen configuration, I need to run `doxygen file_name` in cmd.

But I want to run everything from Perl.

I tried this code

```
my $cmd = "perl -w otherscript.pl";
my $result = system("start $cmd");
```

But it just opens a cmd window. I need to execute cmd code directly through Perl (not a Perl command line, but through a Perl IDE). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: for what is the `start` ?? and did you tried it with backticks instead of a system call?

Comment: "start" is to start cmd. It pops out cmd window on screen

Comment: Why do you want it to run in a different window?

Comment: coz when i run this my $result = `doxygen C:\Users\aghosh\abcd`; or my $result = `doxygen "C:\Users\aghosh\abcd"`; compiler gives error as Error: configuration file C:SERSGHOSHBCD not found!

Comment: but from cmd it works fine. I guess perl can't locate the file path

Comment: oops.got my ans.made a silly mistake should use "/" instead of "\".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `system` and `start` is OK.

From your description in the comment, I think it's because you're not using the correct escaping method when giving configure files to Doxygen that it throws such an error:

> Error: configuration file C:SERSGHOSHBCD not found!

Try with

```
my $result = `doxygen C:\\Users\\aghosh\\abcd`;
```

In the two back-slashes, the former one is to escape the latter one, so that it's recognized by Windows as the directory separator.

Comment: yes. just saw your answer now. you are rite.made a silly mistake using "/" instead of "\" also works. But i will use "\\" as it feels more appropriate. Thanks